# unresolved reference invokeOnCancellation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm still learning Kotlin so bare with me....

Why do i get a "unresolved reference invokeOnCancellation" with this following code

```
suspend fun getEntireJobMapFromFirebase() = suspendCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->

        val database = Firebase.database
        val job = database.getReference("jobs")
        val listener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                // This method is called whenever data at this location is updated.
                Log.d(jobMapTag, "job map value from firebase is: $dataSnapshot")
                commonViewModel.updateJobCategoryList(dataSnapshot)
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(jobMapTag, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
                continuation.resumeWithException(error.toException())
            }
        }
        job.addValueEventListener(listener)
        continuation.invokeOnCancellation { job.removeEventListener(listener) }
        // remove the listener when the coroutine is cancelled

    }
```

i have the dependency `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'`

even if i change to continuation.invokeOnCompletion {} it's still a unresolved reference

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are using [suspendCoroutine<Unit>](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html), so the type of your `continuation` variable is `Continuation<Unit>`. This type doesn't have the methods or extensions you're trying to use, hence the error.

`invokeOnCancellation` is defined on `CancellableContinuation`, which you would get if you used [suspendCancellableCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) instead.

`invokeOnCompletion` is defined on the `Job` type, which is an unrelated type in this case.

---

Taking a step back, I'm not well versed in the Firebase API, but it seems you're trying to wrap a multi-shot callback into a suspend function, which is not appropriate. This kind of adapter with `suspendCancellableCoroutine` is meant to wrap callback-based functions that fire their callback *only once* (when they get the result, or an error).

If you do want to listen to a single event, probably you want to call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead. But if this is not for learning purposes, note that there are already wrappers around the `Task` API. You can for instance use the `Task<T>.await()` extension provided by:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services

For multi-shot callbacks, you might want to wrap your Firebase API into a [callbackFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) instead.